# SQLite Upsert using trigger

Tags: sqlite

Hello I made a trigger for aborting not changed rows
But now I want to make a trigger for Upserting (insert Or update) rows
works with before insert that when a row exists , update that row , else insert
i want to do these using triggers

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for a table; you cannot abort the INSERT operation without raising an actual error.

Comment: well, actually i'm raising an actual error (RAISE (ABORT,'Error'))

Comment: That would not be an UPSERT.

Comment: I know , i want to do an upsert via trigger